# number of comparisons median quicksort

Tags: quicksort, median

How do I compute number of comparisons in median quick sort? Where must I increment my counter to compute this? My code of median quick sort below:

```
void my_swap(vector<int>&vect, int dex1, int dex2) {
   int temp = vect[dex1];
   vect[dex1] = vect[dex2];
   vect[dex2] = temp;
}
int find_median(vector<int>&vect, int p, int r) {
   int center = (p + r) / 2;
   if (vect[p] > vect[center])
      my_swap(vect, p, center);
   if (vect[p] > vect[r])
      my_swap(vect, p, r);
   if (vect[center] > vect[r])
      my_swap(vect, center, r);
   my_swap(vect, center, r - 1);
   return vect[r - 1];
}
void standart_sort(vector<int>&vect, int p, int r) {
   if (r - p + 1 <= 1){
      return;
   }
   if (r - p + 1 == 2) {
      if (vect[p] > vect[r]){
         my_swap(vect, p, r);
      }
      return;
   } else {
      if (vect[p] > vect[r - 1]){
         my_swap(vect, p, r - 1);
      }
      if (vect[p] > vect[r]){
         my_swap(vect, p, r);
      }
      if (vect[r - 1] > vect[r]){
         my_swap(vect, r - 1, r);
      }
   }
}
int partition_for_median(vector<int>&vect, int p, int r, double pivot) {
   double x = pivot;
   int i = p - 1;
   for(int j = p; j <= r - 1; j++)
   {
      counter++; //pasted here
      if(vect[j] <= x)
      {
         i++;
         my_swap(vect, i, j);
      }
   }
   my_swap(vect, i + 1, r);
   return i; 
}
void quick_sort_median(vector<int>&vect, int p, int r) {
   if (r - p + 1 <= 3){
      counter2++;
      standart_sort(vect, p, r);
   }
   else {
      double median = find_median(vect, p, r);
      int partition = partition_for_median(vect, p, r, median);
      quick_sort_median(vect, p, partition - 1);
      quick_sort_median(vect, partition + 1, r);
   }
}
```

For example in this array `{3,7,5,1,9,6,4,10,8,2}` there are `25` comparisons, but how do I calculate that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom comparison function that does the usual integer comparison but also increment a global counter. A similar idea is to wrap int in a custom class with its own comparison function doing something similar. The class would have a static counter.

A more hackish way is to do the instrumentation directly in your code. Find every place in your code where a comparison happens and increment a counter.